# Name Error "uninitialized constant" ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want update data in database using `update_attributes` with special condition (condition work fine)

Code :

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
  def language_config
   current_user=Authorization.current_user
    logger.info "9"
    if params[:examination_id] ==1
        logger.info "3"

     LanguageSetting.find(:all, :conditions => "section = 'examination'")
    logger.info "1"
     LanguageSetting.update_attributes(:language =>"english")
          
    else 
          logger.info "2"

     LanguageSetting.find(:all, :conditions => "section = 'examination'")
     LanguageSetting.update_attributes(:language =>"arabic")
    end
    
    
  end
end
```

In log file we found :

```
Parameters: {"controller"=>"languages", "action"=>"language_config"}
Username : admin Role : Admin
9
2

NameError (uninitialized constant LanguagesController::LanguageSetting):
```

That mean condition work fine but why Name error ?
Table in database named : `language_settings`

Why i recieve this error ? Btw i don't create a model i think i dont need or i am wrong ?

Please need help with information

Comment: are you trying to update all `LanguageSetting` or specific one ?

Comment: specific one for testing

Comment: *"Btw i don't create a model i think i dont need or i am wrong?"* --- You're wrong. The class doesn't magically exist. You need to define the class in order for the class to be defined.

Comment: that right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with a database table, you need a model.

For the bare minimum, just create an `app/models/language_setting.rb` with the following (If you're using something less than Rails 5, inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` instead)

```
class LanguageSetting < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Rails models work by looking at the schema to auto-generate getter/setter methods for the various attributes. That's why, with the model in place, you could say:

```
setting = LanguageSetting.new 
setting.language = "english"
setting.save
```

As well as the code you've shown in your question.

Comment: Great, but why i put setting.language = "english" ?

Comment: can u tell me what i should put in model? if my database contain (id, language, section , school_id) And my goal change language from arabic to english or english to arabic (as string) for each section

Comment: It was just an example. You don't have to put anything in your model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model to communicate with the table in the database. I recommend reading official rails [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

And in the code, you are apply condition on the model but not storing its results. `:update_attributes` is an instance method of ActiveRecord::Model class.

So what you are doing can be achieved like below. First define the model.

```rb
     settings = LanguageSetting.where("section = 'examination'")
     settings.update_attributes(:language =>"arabic")
```

Comment: Great, i will try this

Comment: can u tell me what i should put in model?
if my database contain (id, language, section , school_id) 
And my goal change language from arabic to english or english to arabic (as string) for each section

Comment: @MhdJawad As I said earlier, you should read the rails guide. It's very easy and will help you understand how to use models in rails to communicate with the database.

Comment: Wouldn't this have to be `find_by` instead of `where`?